# Set ng-model value from outside javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an chrome extension (just to myself, for now) and I want to set a input value of the website that is using ngModel (bind value: `<input [(ngModel)]="value">`) by the javascript and I don't want to change the website's code. It's possible?
I tried using element.setAttribute("ng-reflect-model", 1234) but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you update the input's value then you need to dispatch an input event to trigger ngModel updating.

```
let input = document.someDOMFunctionToSelectInput();
input.value = 'updated value';
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false }));
```

Here is a StackBlitz with a button outside of the Angular app https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ksgn4

Comment: Thanks so much! And how can I set focus so the angular can validade the input? Like activate [disabled], (change) or [ngClass]?